# What is the difference between isnull on temp table vs isnull on original table?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008

I am using SQL to concatenate strings together.

This statement works:

```
DECLARE @FirstNamesString nvarchar(256)
SELECT
    @FirstNamesString = COALESCE(@FirstNamesString + ', ', '') + p.FirstName 
FROM 
    Person p
ORDER BY
    p.SortOrder
```

And I get the list of first names like:

`Name1, Name2, Name3`

Now I want to add in a possibly null last name field for each of these persons.  I tried the sql below but I only get the last item in the list (`Name3`):

```
DECLARE @FirstNamesString nvarchar(256)
SELECT @FirstNamesString = COALESCE(@FirstNamesString + ', ', '') + p.FirstName + ISNULL(' ' + p.LastName, '') 
FROM 
    Person p
ORDER BY
    p.SortOrder
```

BUT if I first insert all of these names into a temp table, then everything works as expected:

```
CREATE TABLE #Person2
(
     FirstName nvarchar(128) NOT NULL
    ,LastName nvarchar(256) NULL
    ,SortOrder int NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO #Person2 (FirstName, LastName, SortOrder) (
    SELECT p.FirstName, p.LastName, p.SortOrder FROM Person p)

DECLARE @FirstNamesString nvarchar(256)

SELECT @FirstNamesString = COALESCE(@FirstNamesString + ', ', '') + p.FirstName + ISNULL(' ' + p.LastName, '') 
FROM 
    #Person2 p
ORDER BY
    p.SortOrder

DROP TABLE #Person2
```

So what is the difference between the statement above against the original table and the one against the temp table?  The temp table route works and I am going to use that but I am very curious... what am I missing here?

**UPDATED WITH POSSIBLE SOLUTION**

See [@Martin's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5219402/what-is-the-difference-between-isnull-on-temp-table-vs-isnull-on-original-table/5219482#5219482) but the concatenation of strings isn't guaranteed to work.  So a solution is to insert the last name into the temp table first prior to selecting the list of first names:

```
CREATE TABLE #Person2
(
     FirstName nvarchar(256) NOT NULL
    ,SortOrder int NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO #Person2 (FirstName, SortOrder) (
    SELECT p.FirstName + ISNULL(' ' + p.LastName, ''), p.SortOrder
    FROM Person p

)

DECLARE @FirstNamesString nvarchar(256)

SELECT
    @FirstNamesString = COALESCE(@FirstNamesString + ', ', '') + p.FirstName  
FROM 
    #Person2 p
ORDER BY
    p.SortOrder ASC
```

Comment: What is the datatype of `p.FirstName`? is that single byte meaning that there is an additional `cast` in the plan?

Comment: Datatype of Person.FirstName is nvarchar(128) NOT NULL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This approach to concatenate strings isn't guaranteed to work. Microsoft say ["The correct behavior for an aggregate concatenation query is undefined."](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287515/en-us). It will fail if the compute scalar ends up in the wrong place in the plan. Can you show both plans?

You could/should of course just use `XML PATH` to concatenate strings as you are on SQL Server 2008 and this is <strike>documented to work.</strike> reliable in current versions.

Example:

```
DECLARE @FirstNamesString nvarchar(256) 

SELECT @FirstNamesString = (
SELECT CASE
         WHEN ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (p.SortOrder)) = 1 THEN ''
         ELSE ','
       END + p.FirstName + ISNULL(' ' + p.LastName, '')
FROM   Person p
ORDER  BY p.SortOrder
FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE  

).value('.[1]','nvarchar(256)')


PRINT @FirstNamesString
```

Comment: "this is documented to work."? Do you have a reference please? I always thought it was an internal thing that happened to do what we wanted...

Comment: @gbn - Passing the buck a bit but [Adam Machanic's comment here](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2006/07/12/rowset-string-concatenation-which-method-is-best.aspx). Why what undocumented aspect do you think it uses?

Comment: Dunno. I've seen it mentioned several times here by SQL types. I've asked an MVP colleague to see what he can dig up. Interesting comments though. Update: http://www.projectdmx.com/tsql/rowconcatenate.aspx#BBXML

Comment: @gbn - Interesting I've changed my last sentence as I don't really know enough about `XML PATH` or why it works.

Comment: @Martin - Is there a way to display the actual execution plan in text?

Comment: @Jeff `SET STATISTICS PROFILE ON` (for the actual plan) or `SET SHOWPLAN_TEXT ON` (the last one is probably more suitable for this purpose but it is the estimated plan)

Comment: Quoting my colleague: "For maximum XML publishing performance FOR XML does steaming XML formatting of the resulting rowset and directly sends its output to the server side TDS code in small chunks without buffering whole XML in the server space." which is taken from http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlprogrammability/archive/2006/04/13/576095.aspx
reads to me that microsoft just adds XML stuff to the final resultset while producing the output from the resultset of the query and since this query is guaranteed to be ordered, so is the XML.

Comment: @Martin -The plans for are different.  The one query that works has a single compute scalar expression whereas the one that fails has 2 compute scalar expressions. (The plans get cut off so posting them is probably not going to help much.)

Comment: @Martin - Since this is just a plan difference, will/may my tempdb method  also start failing at some random time in the future?

Comment: @Jeff - Quite possibly yes. You can't use a plan guide to fix the location of compute scalars in the plan and the only obvious reason I can think of for different plans would be different statistics.

Comment: @Martin - Thanks for your help.  Looks like it will be best for me to concatenate first name to last name (if necessary) when inserting into the temp table and then select out the list.  I updated my question with this possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it works fine. But the variable engine is indeed not guaranteed to work. (and it is undocumented)

```
create table Person(FirstName nvarchar(10), LastName nvarchar(20), SortOrder int)

insert into Person 
VALUES ('Pers1', 'Last1', 1),
       ('Pers2', 'Last2', 2),
       ('Pers3', 'Last3', 3),
       ('Pers4', 'Last4', 4),
       ('Pers5', NULL, 5)

DECLARE @FirstNamesString nvarchar(256)
SELECT @FirstNamesString = COALESCE(@FirstNamesString + ', ', '') + p.FirstName + ISNULL(' ' + p.LastName, '') 
FROM 
    Person p
ORDER BY
    p.SortOrder

print @FirstNamesString
```